# Storing array of large dictionaries with Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

In Swift, I have an array containing dictionaries. Each dictionary contains about 5 key value pairs. One value is a dictionary of its own, this dictionary containing up to 65ish pairs.

How can I effectively store this information with Core Data? I'm new to Swift and this kind of database. I have tried searching, but what I have found is difficult to make sense of. Thanks.

Comment: You can also do this with an info Plist as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a database that is easily writeable. I also will likely want to integrate with iCloud.

Comment: Have you seen the ray wenderlich tutorials? http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: I have, but he doesn't cover storing dictionaries etc. or nested objects

Comment: Are the keys consistent?  If so, you should map them to attributes of a managed object.  The attribute name would be the key, and its value, the value for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to search the dictionary's keys or values, you can serialize your dictionary to NSData and save it as binary data.

Otherwise, you'll have to setup an entity to hold a key and value, store a particular dictionary's keys and values, then relate those nested entities to their parent.  Each object in a particular Set would be a key/value pair.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should create a proper and robust data model to keep managing your data flexible.

Your top level entity would have 4 attributes and one to-many relationship, your child entity (representing the 65ish dictionary) would have 2+ attributes holding the key and the corresponding data respectively.